# FreePascal & OpenShift

Tags: openshift, freepascal

any one has experience with Open Shift and install FreePascal as a cartridge?
I found this but I don't know how make it work :
https://github.com/jhadvig/openshift-pascal-cartridge
I want to know what is the instruction of making FreePascal cartridge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command should install that cartridge for you

```
rhc app create freepascal https://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect?github=jhadvig/openshift-pascal-cartridge
```

Basically since the manifest.yml file does not contain a Source-Url definition, you need to run it through the cartridge reflector as i did above.

Unfortunately that cartridge also does not seem to install correctly.  You should leave an "issue" using the issues tab on that cartridge asking if it is ready for production use or not.

If you want to develop your own cartridge, you can read through the cartridge developers guide here: http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html

Comment: Thank you.I will wait for answer of issue.